# C++ How to set a private class member in a namespace within a static library?

Tags: c++, class, static, namespaces, private

Hi there fellow nerds,

i got a problem while tryin to code a static library. Im trying to set a private class member with a public class function. The class is located in a namespace. When i try to compile the example program (namespace_test) i get a LNK2001 Error stating a not resolved external symbol.

(Fehler 1   error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""private: static bool ns_test::CTest::m_bPrivateMember" (?m_bPrivateMember@CTest@ns_test@@0_NA)". ...\ns_test\namespace_test\namespace_test_api.lib(CTest.obj)    namespace_test
)

How can i correctly implement that function?

Here is my code:

## namespace_test_api.proj

namespace.h

```
namespace ns_test
{
    class CTest
    {
    public:
        CTest();
        ~CTest();

        static void SetPrivateMember(bool i_bPrivateMember);
        static bool bGetPrivateMember();

    private:
        static bool m_bPrivateMember;
    };
}
```

CTest.cpp

```
#include "namespace.h"
namespace ns_test
{
    CTest::CTest()
    {
    }
    CTest::~CTest()
    {
    }

    void CTest::SetPrivateMember(bool i_bPrivateMember)
    {
        CTest::m_bPrivateMember = i_bPrivateMember;
    }

    bool CTest::bGetPrivateMember()
    {
        return CTest::m_bPrivateMember;
    }
}
```

## namepsace_test.proj

namspace.h

```
namespace ns_test
{
    class CTest
    {
    public:
        CTest();
        ~CTest();

        static void SetPrivateMember(bool i_bPrivateMember);
        static bool bGetPrivateMember();

    private:
        static bool m_bPrivateMember;
    };
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "namespace.h"


#pragma comment (lib, "namespace_test_api.lib")



int main()
{
    ns_test::CTest::SetPrivateMember(true);
    std::cout << "PrivateMember: " << ns_test::CTest::bGetPrivateMember() << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I also might encourage you to not name files the exact same thing as C++ keywords (in this case, namespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CTest.cpp, you need to add the line:

```
bool ns_test::CTest::m_bPrivateMember;
```

This `defines` the static member, the entry in the class only `declares` it.

Note that the above will initialise it with `false`. You may want to make that explicit, or `true`:

```
bool ns_test::CTest::m_bPrivateMember = true;
```

Note this is an example of the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule): you need to `define` each global exactly once.

Comment: that did it! thank you for that very quick awnser! +++